# Django filter many to many list of objects that contains all the items of a list

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Models.py

```
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name='track_related')
```

artist_list = [mila, fuad, habib]

I have to filter all the track that's artists contain all the artist from artist_list Mila, Fuad, and Habib
I tried

```
Track.objects.filter(artists__in=artist_list).annotate(num_artist=Count('artists')).filter(num_artist=len(artist_list))
```

But its not woking and also i think my logic isnt fully correct.

Comment: Is your `artist_list` a list of `Artist` objects, or a list of strings?

Comment: Its Artist objects not list of strings.

Comment: exactly what is not working with the query? Does it raise an error, shows tracks with more/less/different/... artists?

Comment: artist_list = [aurthohin, balam]
if I run this query then its showing tracks that contain All the artists and also showing Track contains All the artists from artist_list plus other artists.
its also showing this track
<QuerySet [<Artist: Aurthohin>, <Artist: Balam>, <Artist: Shironamhin>]>

Comment: what Django version do you use?

Comment: Using Django 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The logic will return *all* the `Track`s that contain *at least* the artists you mention. Indeed, because you filter the related model, the `Count('artists')` will count the ones after filtering. But artists that are not in the `artists_list` will not be taken into account.

You can however implement this by performing two counts: (1) the total number of related artists, and (2) the filtered set of artists.

We can implement that by making use of the [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) of the aggregate function:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count

Track.objects.annotate(
    num_artist=Count('artists', filter=Q(artists__in=artist_list))
).filter(
    Q(num_artist=Count('artists')),
    num_artist=len(artist_list)
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but its always returning empty queryset as a result. check my screenshot link  https://ibb.co/grpfLYV

Comment: @AbuSayem: are you sure these are the same `Artist` *objects*? Not just `Artist`s with the same name (in other words, do the primary keys match)?

Comment: @AbuSayem: can you edit the question and share how the `TrackQuerySet` works?